# Hello! I have been trying to install pyAudio for some time now but i keep getting errors

Tags: python, pyaudio

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\don clivo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Don Clivo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h3d3buha\\pyaudio_b7467f4b8eef466cbdb69deff17b21f8\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Don Clivo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h3d3buha\\pyaudio_b7467f4b8eef466cbdb69deff17b21f8\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Don Clivo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e7sn4vl6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\don clivo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\Don Clivo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3d3buha\pyaudio_b7467f4b8eef466cbdb69deff17b21f8\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\don clivo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Don Clivo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h3d3buha\\pyaudio_b7467f4b8eef466cbdb69deff17b21f8\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Don Clivo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-h3d3buha\\pyaudio_b7467f4b8eef466cbdb69deff17b21f8\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Don Clivo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-e7sn4vl6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\don clivo\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\pyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Did you try the part where it says "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with ...."

Comment: please, download c++ build tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/